# Dell Optiplex 990 Bios Corrupted

Tags: boot, dell, bios

I have an issue with dell optiplex 990, i am getting no bootable hard disk found error.

Videos as below

https://photos.app.goo.gl/6TocW3sAoM7RL8gV9

Problem: I tried to boot into USB drive which has windows 10, but unable to. The Bios Screen Boot Sequence is completely empty it does not have any way to select, nor i am able to see any of the boot details.

Steps taken: I disconnected both my hard disk configured in raid mode and plugged them to a different pc and formatted all the drives (including the 300 mb drive allocated for system). Then Connected only 1 hard disk without any data in it and configured to AHCI Mode.

I have inserted the jumper to reset the bios password mode, at least it boots now and able to get into boot screen. But still unable to proceed further

Then Connected a bootable windows 10 usb drive also a windows 10 dvd and tried to boot into it - but unable to boot into that as well.
Created a bootable dos pendrive using rufus and added dell opt

Kindly help

Comment: I am looking forward to fix my PC to be able to boot into my USB installer after formatting everything. I am unable to boot into pendrive to select the pendrive to boot into. Please view the video to understand the problem faced before just down voting the question

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

1. Reconnect the password jumper to the original location.
2. Remove the CMOS battery from the system board for 5 minutes while the power is disconnected from the system.

Then, boot the system and see if the boot settings change.

The problem with your system is it does not support UEFI booting which makes it hard to install Windows 10. In my environment, I network boot the older dells to Windows PE and then run the installer from there. You might be able to create a Windows PE boot CD-ROM and then run the windows installer from there. You will not be able to make a bootable USB drive unless you are using a older flash drive.